# F# Linq To SQL commiting changes doesn't do anything

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#

I've got following class defined in F#, with mapping attributes for Linq to SQL:

```
[<Table(Name="Expense")>]
type public Expense(datetime : Nullable<DateTime>, value, category, comment) = 
    let mutable id = 0
    let mutable datetime = if datetime.HasValue then datetime.Value else DateTime.Now
    let mutable value = value
    let mutable category = category
    let mutable comment = comment
    [<Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)>]
    member x.ExpenseID with get() = id and set v = id <- v
    [<Column>]
    member x.DateTime with get() = datetime and set v = datetime <- v
    [<Column>] 
    member x.Value with get() = value and set v = value <- v
    [<Column>] 
    member x.Category with get() = category and set v = category <- v    
    [<Column>] 
    member x.Comment with get() = comment and set v = comment <- v
    new() = Expense(nl, 0m, "", "")
```

Then I want to insert new object of that type, using following code (fragment):

```
member private x.expenses = (new DataContext(connString)).GetTable<Expense>()
    member x.Add (expense : Expense) = 
        x.expenses.InsertOnSubmit(expense)
        x.expenses.Context.SubmitChanges()
```

Calling SubmitChanges() doesn't do anything, nor any exception is thrown. So I tried to check, if there is something with it being an F# object, and I've declared other class in C#, with exactly same mappings. Then I was able to insert new record. Now I'm wondering, what's the difference?

Did some Reflector investigation, the only difference are attributes [CompilerGenerated] on C# auto getters/setters, and [Serializable] and CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.ObjectType)] on F# class...could it be one of those?

Reflector disassemblies: http://pastebin.com/qTRfVcmm

// EDIT

By doing some debugging against .NET framework code, I've noticed that internal list of tracked objects of the DataContext instance is not consistent between InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges call. At the beginning of the SubmitChanges call, this list is empty. That led me to thinking, those two references are not targeting same DataContext instance, and VS debugger confirmed that. Still, no idea why.

Comment: Is the connection string the same in C# and your F# projects?

Comment: Aye, in fact the F# code is called from C# assembly.

Comment: By doing some debugging against .NET framework code, I've noticed that internal list of tracked objects of the DataContext instance is not consistent between InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges call. At the beginning of the SubmitChanges call, this list is empty, like if it was entirely different instance than the one InsertOnSubmit was operating on... // edit: in fact it IS different instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the first use of `member`. F# members (without paramaters) behave like properties, so you're creating new data context each time you access `x.expenses`. To correct that, you can store the table object in a field using `let`:

```
type SomeType() =
  let expenses = (new DataContext(connString)).GetTable<Expense>()     
  member x.Add (expense : Expense) =          
    expenses.InsertOnSubmit(expense)
    expenses.Context.SubmitChanges()
```

The `member x.Foo = <expr>` syntax in F# corresponds to a property with getter, so in the C# syntax, your original code would look like this:

```
Table<Expenses> Expenses {
  get { return (new DataContext(connString)).GetTable<Expense>(); }
}
```

...which explains why there were multiple copies of the data context created.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, during my investigation I even changed the code to have some locally defined DataContext (so that it wouldn't be re-created for sure), but maybe I'm not gonna tell what embarassing thing I did, which blocked that thing from compiling ;)

Comment: Won't you have problems disposing the connection like this?

Comment: Justin is right - having a data context per instance doesn't seem like a good idea from a scalability standpoint, and at what point are you calling Dispose() on the context instance to close its underlying connection to the database?

Comment: @justin @Joel Yes, you're right - it is better idea to pass the data context as argument. I just wanted to explain what was wrong with the original codde (and didn't think about the overall design)

Comment: It's most likely because I've pasted only snippet of the code. The class responsible for Adding and owning this DataContext is just a singleton (repository).